# enumareteChildNodes with collision detection swift

Tags: swift, background, collision-detection, skshapenode, sklabelnode

I am trying to code a word collision detection game.

The problem is that before I add rectangle as a background of my words, all of my codes are working, I can detect the collision and take action. but after add rectangle, I have to change my parents of the word and I add it as the child of background.

This the function that I create word:

```
func giveWords() {

    randomIndex = Int.random(in: 0 ..< lastWords.count)

    word = SKLabelNode(text: "\(lastWords[randomIndex])")
    lastWords.remove(at: randomIndex)
    word.fontSize = 17
    word.name = "word"
    word.fontName = "HelveticaNeue-Bold"

    backgroundWord = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (word.frame.width + 3), height: (word.frame.height + 2)), cornerRadius: 4)

    word.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: self.size)
    word.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask    = 0
    word.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask  = 0
    word.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask     = 1
    word.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    word.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    word.position = CGPoint(x:(backgroundWord.position.x + word.frame.width/2 + 1 ), y: (backgroundWord.position.y) + 4)

    let number = Int.random(in: 1 ..< 9)
    backgroundWord.position = CGPoint(x: (50 * number), y: 450)

    word.zPosition = 3
    backgroundWord.zPosition = 3
    backgroundWord.addChild(word)
    addChild(backgroundWord)

}
```

and this is the code that I check collision:

```
func checkCollision() {

    enumerateChildNodes(withName: "word") { (node, _) in

        let word = node as! SKLabelNode

        if self.basketNode.frame.intersects(word.frame) {
            if self.similarWord.contains(word.text!) {
                self.score += 1
                self.scoreLabel.text = "\(self.score)"
                self.takeWord.append(word.text!)
                self.run(self.trueSound)
                self.backgroundWord.removeFromParent()

            } else {
                self.run(self.falseSound)
                self.health -= 1
                self.healthLabel.text = "HP: \(self.health)"
                self.backgroundWord.removeFromParent()

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried physics collision but I did not handle, so I chose this algorithm.

After function called, `self.basketNode.frame.intersects(word.frame)` returns false, this means collision is not detected.

I couldn't handle why collision is not detected.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, here is the answer and reason.

The reason behind it is, and the reason why I did not detect `self.basketNode.frame.intersects(word.frame)` is simple.

I tried to detect word's frame intersection but I should detect its parent which is the background. So I changed the word to the background and after that create a let that help me to access word. Here is the answer btw...

```
    func checkCollision() {

    enumerateChildNodes(withName: "word") { (node, _) in
        let background = node as! SKShapeNode
        if self.basketNode.frame.intersects(background.frame) {
            if let word = background.childNode(withName: "string word") as? SKLabelNode {
                if self.similarWord.contains(word.text!) {
                    self.score += 1
                    self.scoreLabel.text = "\(self.score)"
                    self.takeWord.append(word.text!)
                    self.run(self.trueSound)
                    word.removeFromParent()
                    background.removeFromParent()
                } else {
                    self.run(self.falseSound)
                    self.health -= 1
                    self.healthLabel.text = "HP: \(self.health)"
                    word.removeFromParent()
                    background.removeFromParent()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

btw I got helped from Apple documentation

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483024-enumeratechildnodes

Thanks for your effort, I am continuing my project.